# What happens to a svn branch when its parent is deleted?

Tags: svn

Let's say Bob is working on branch A, and you want to create your own branch called B, copied from A.  What happens if Bob merges A back into trunk, deletes it, then recreates it again (while you're still working on B)? Will svn freak out when you merge B back into A2?  How does svn treat this situation?  I couldn't find any info about this in the svn book.

*update*

I'm still waiting for an answer about how svn knows what to do here... but if you just want to know if things won't blow up, it looks like they won't.  I tried it myself (using svn 1.8, which is pretty new).  It seems to be fine--no errors or complaints when I merged the orphaned branch into a new branch (they all started from trunk).  I don't know if everything would be fine though in 1.7 where you might make use of `merge --reintegrate`.  Here's a view of the TortoiseSVN log file.  Notice the way the revisions are ordered and arranged.. I guess that shows the way the tree magically works itself out.  The "creating fresh dev step" is interesting because it happened in a revision later than the A branch modifications (rev 5 and 7), yet it the log arranges it like it came before those steps.  There's definitely some svn cleverness going on.
[image]